# php integrated advertisement between data which comes via loop?

Tags: php

simply i assume how to place a advertisement between data which is fetched by loop.
for example :

```
<?php   
 $i=0;
    while($i<11){
    echo $i."<br/>";
    $i++;
    }
?>
```

and the result is :

```
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    10
```

and i want this result:

```
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    -----my advertisement------
    6
    7
    8
    9
    10
```

any suggestion for it?

Comment: It will be after 5th row or some logic is there? Please provide more info.

Comment: no i want only 1 ad @SureshKamrushi

Comment: Than answer given by hsz seems correct. (simple logic, what is stopping you?)

Comment: sorry i am out of my mind. what a stupid one i am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY THIS

```
 <?php   
$i=0;
while($i<11){

if($i == 6)
{
   'place your advertisement';
}
 echo $i."<br/>";
$i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: It will print after 6 item...

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ) {
  echo ($i + 1) + '<br/>';
  if ( $i == 5 ) {
    echo '-----my advertisement------';
  }
}
```